# rename hundreds of file by removing last few characters

Tags: rename, filenames

I have hundreds of file andI want to remove last 7 characters from the filename but keeping its extension.

Old name:

```
abc_xyz12_4567.txt

abcde_xyz12_4567.txt
```

New name:

```
abc_xyz.txt

abcde_xyz.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
ls | awk -F. '{printf "mv %s %s.%s\n",$0,substr($1,1,length($1)-7),$2 ;}' | ksh
```

you can use

```
ls | awk -F. '{printf "mv %s %s.%s\n",$0,substr($1,1,length($1)-7),$2 ;}'
```

to have a preview.

Comment: (assuming the file names contain only one dot and no shell special characters).

Comment: for spaces in the files use ls | awk -F. '{printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s.%s\"\n",$0,substr($1,1,length($1)-7),$2 ;}' | ksh

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rename](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/prename/) (Or `prename` in some OS):

```
rename 's/.{7}(\.txt)/$1/' abc*
```

Comment: `rename` sometimes goes as `prename` (perl-rename), depending on the specific OS (there is another command called `rename`, which uses a more `tr`-like syntax and is generally inferior).

Comment: @evilsoup: Yes, added that note.

Answer (score -1):

with GNU `tar`:

```
touch abc_xyz12_4567.txt abcde_xyz12_4567.txt
tar --remove-files --xform='s/\(.*\).\{7\}\./\1./' -c ./* | tar -x
ls
```

#### OUTPUT

```
abcde_xyz.txt  abc_xyz.txt
```

That will do it all safely - and in fact you don't even need the `--remove-files` option - you might instead `untar` the files to a different directory and verify the filename change worked. Maybe like:

```
tar --xform... | tar -C ../test -x
```